# why is this jQuery hover state is unaligned in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, webkit, hover

I've recently published a website (http://www.howrad.me) and everything works well, except for hovering in Safari. The overlay `pgaTitle` does not line up with the image `pgaPhoto`.

Here is a code example from the drawings section (http://howrad.me/tattoos.html#drawings)

```
        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" title="2012 baybay" href="images/2012/1.jpg">
        <div class="pgaPhoto">
        <div class="pgaTitle" style="display: none;">
        <h2>2012</h2>
        </div>  
        <img src="images/covers/drawing2012.jpg" />
        </div></a>


        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb3" title="figure study"href="images/2009/drawings/1.jpg">
         <div class="pgaPhoto">
         <div class="pgaTitle" style="display: none;">
        <h2>2010</h2>
        </div>  
        <img src="images/covers/drawing2010.jpg" />
        </div></a>
```

The html syntax seems fine by me, and the jquery below is working fine:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pgaPhoto").hover(function() {
                $(this).find(".pgaTitle").stop().fadeTo(300, 1 , function() {
                });
            } , function() { //on hover out...
                $(this).find(".pgaTitle").fadeTo(300, 0);
            });
        });
```

I just don't understand why the hover states for the left side images are slightly off, especially when I have no real issues in other browsers. any help?? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: You have invalid html. `<a>` elements can't contain `<div>` elements.

Comment: The HTML has errors.  There should be a space before the `href="...` attribute.  Recommend you pass it through an HTML validator to find this and other problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixed up between your block and inline elements.

```
<a> is an inline element
<div> is a block element
```

Blocks can contain inline elements, but inline elements **cannot** contain blocks.

Whenever you put a block inside an inline element, browsers will find a way to resolve the difference, but you will get invalid HTML and suffer more bugs.

To resolve your problem, either put your `<div>` blocks outside your `<a>` elements, or replace your `<div>`s with their closest inline equivalent: `<span>`.

Comment: Except his `pgaPhoto` class is defined as `display: inline;` in style.css.  So why not make it a `span`

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Using <span> is both valid HTML and a more elegant solution because it is warranted in this case.

Comment: Hey guys thanks so much for your response! I've changed my divs inside of my <a> tags to spans but I'm still going through the same issue, where the hover state is slightly shifted to the left on my left-side images. where am i going wrong here? This issue ONLY comes up in safari